# Calendar Plugin

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, calendar

What would be the best Calendar plugin I may use in a asp.net application that is open source that allows for weekly, daily and monthly viewing?. I was looking at some online but I am not sure which of those is the best. Do you have any in mind that I may use and that I could integrate in my application.

I saw some nice ones using JQuery, Is there anything similar to a Google calendar that I may use in my asp.net application?.

Comment: By Google calendar, do you mean something like [this](https://www.google.com/calendar/)? Or perhaps you mean a datepicker similar to the ones in [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)?

Comment: Yeah not the date picker, something like the first one you linked there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

planscalendar & fullcalendar

http://www.planscalendar.com/demo/

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/